# Randomly access map entry given the key in java

Tags: java, dictionary, generics

I have a dictionary of type `Map<?, String>`. The key type is unknown at runtime. I still can call `get()` with, say, a string and if such an element exists, I correctly get the stored object.

Now I modify that object, and want to put it back in the dictionary. Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
    Map<String, String> hat = new HashMap<>();
    hat.put("bunny", "rabbit");
    Map<?, String> magicHat = hat;
    String trick = magicHat.get("bunny");
    if (trick != null) {
        trick = "jack".concat(trick);
        magicHat.put("bunny", trick);
    }
```

However, and understandably, the call `magicHat.put("bunny", trick);` gives the following compilation error: `incompatible types: String cannot be converted to CAP#1`.

One way to work around it is to use streams (or to iterate) to get the map's entry, and then use the entry to amend the value:

```
    Map.Entry<?, String> entry = magicHat.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> "bunny".equals(e.getKey()))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
    if (entry != null) {
        String trick = "jack".concat(entry.getValue());
        entry.setValue(trick);
    }
```

In real-life however I'm bound to Java 6 and cannot afford the comfort of streams. Iterating over all the entries seems inefficient.

Is there an elegant way to randomly access an entry in a map, given its key?

[Here is](https://theonlinecompiler.com/ide/3307/peaceful-af) the code that doesn't compile, and [here is](https://theonlinecompiler.com/ide/3310/peaceful-af) the work around.

Thanks for the insights.

Comment: Why don't you use `Map<Object, String>` instead of `Map<?, String>`?

Comment: The Capture#of (?) doesn't need to be used in this case, use a ```Object``` that you can down and upper cast to anything

Comment: In my case `Map<?, String>` is the type of the formal parameter to a method. I need to use wildcard so I can pass dictionaries with whatever key type. If I use `Map<Object, String>`, I won't be able to call the method with, say, `Map<String, String>` as the actual parameter type since it is not a sub-type of `Map<Object, String>`.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the key-type to Object instead of wildcard (?). In that way, you don't have to know the type. However, you should make sure you never store keys of different types in the map.

```
Map<String, String> hat = new HashMap<>();
hat.put("bunny", "rabbit");
Map<Object, String> magicHat = new HashMap<>();
hat.forEach(magicHat::put); // Edit: Added this
String trick = magicHat.get("bunny"); // String extends Object
if (trick != null) {
    trick = "old".concat(trick);
    magicHat.put("bunny", trick);
}
```

In most cases, the solution to this problem would be to use generic type variables instead. In that way, you still have type-safety but don't have to know the key-type during compile-time.

Comment: This won't work neither. `Map<String, String>` is not a sub-type of `Map<Object, String>`. Now I get the compilation error: Incompatible types when assigning `hat` to `magicHat`.

Comment: I changed the way magicHat was initialized so that it doesn't set itself to hat directly but rather copies to content. That way it compiles.